Puppeteer Paste Key Not Working (CMD + V)
I'm currently using Puppeteer. I'm trying to log in to a Korean website called Naver. However, whenever I try to log in by typing, it always redirects me to a captcha page, preventing me from proceeding. I use the following code:
await page.click("#id");
await page.type("#id", "your_ID");

From what I've researched online, copying the ID to the clipboard and pasting it into the ID input field avoids triggering the captcha, allowing for login. So, I tried to save it to the clipboard and then paste using Puppeteer, but the paste operation doesn’t work. Here’s what I’ve tried:
const ncp = require("node-clipboardy");

await ncp.write("your_ID");
await page.click("#id");

await page.keyboard.down("Meta");
await page.keyboard.press("V");
await page.keyboard.up("Meta");

How can I make this work?
This is the Naver login site: https://nid.naver.com/nidlogin.login
I tried pasting because typing in the login input triggers the captcha, but the paste function doesn't work.

Can you share a [mcve]? How you launch the browser (headless or not) and other factors can influence whether you're captcha'd or not.

Does this answer your question? How do you paste text using Puppeteer?
